# Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String while computing the SUM with DATATABLE in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, python-3.x, datatable, sum

I am getting the below error while computing the SUM with DataTable.

```
Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.
```

I am using the below code:

```
lblQuestionnaireTotalTime.Text = CalculateMinutes(
                Convert.ToInt32(
                (
                (DataSet)Session["DsQuestionaire"]).Tables["Questions"]
                .Compute("Sum(EstimatedCompletionTime)", "")));
```

It always throws an error.
I have tried the [how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-the-datatable-column-in-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892993/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-the-datatable-column-in-asp-net) and

[how-can-i-get-a-sum-for-the-column-pieces-in-a-datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902111/how-can-i-get-a-sum-for-the-column-pieces-in-a-datatable)
and some other links but not able to resolve the issue.

Here is how i m adding column to datatable

```
dtQuestions.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EstimatedCompletionTime", typeof(Int32)));
```

Comment: Naive question but...what's the type of EstimatedCompletionTime?

Comment: Did you try with Sum(Convert(EstimatedCompletionTime, 'System.Int32'))?

Comment: it says Compute method takes only 1 parameter

Comment: it says "Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier."

Comment: Someone here on SO (sorry can't find it now) suggested to use LINQ for something like that (it works with DataTable too). Give it a chance!

Comment: I have mentioned in the question links i have tried but it is also not working with that

Comment: Out of interest, what does `((DataSet)Session["DsQuestionaire"]).Tables["Questions"].Columns["EstimatedCompletionTime"].DataType` return? Is it possible the type is being changed somewhere?

Comment: actually session is not destroying on LogOut, actually i am converting a 1.1 website to 4.0 and they just used to redirect to login page when click on Logout. that's is the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compute `Sum` of a Column with type string. You need to make sure your column has type integer.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `(DataSet)Session["DsQuestionaire"]).Tables["Questions"]` has the exact same column type? Can you get its type and check?

Comment: actually session is not destroying on LogOut, actually i am converting a 1.1 website to 4.0 and they just used to redirect to login page when click on Logout. that's is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the column data type

```
t.Columns["Price"].DataType=typeof(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string column.

```
object sumObject = dtTable.Compute("Sum(Convert(" + col_Name + ", 'System.Int32')","");
```